# Moving an email address from webpage to app sign up page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage in which users can enter their email address and click 'start trial' to sign up to our web app. I want this to open the app page with the email address they just filled in, so they just have to select the password they want to complete the sign-up.

I have wrote the javascript code and entered it into the HTML page , but it still doesn't seem to be bringing over the email address used.

Exmaple;
need to redirect user to this page: http://testdomain.com/auth/register?email=[PUT_HERE_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FROM_FORM]

```
$('header .btn-green').click(function (event) {
window.location.href = "http://testdomain.com/auth/register?email="; + $('header input[type="email"]').val();
});
```

It Just inputs [PUT_HERE_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FROM_FORM] into the email field no matter what email address used.

Comment: You let slip a `;` before the `+`, so the rest is ignored! I think you should also encode the email to URL format.

Comment: "It Just inputs [PUT_HERE_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FROM_FORM]" - you mean exactly that text? Where does it get it from? Is it on the page somewhere? I think we'd have to see the HTML too. Or is it a problem with your register page not processing the address it's given correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('header .btn-green').click(function (event) {
window.location.href = "http://testdomain.com/auth/register?email=" + $('header input[type="email"]').val();
});
```

Remove ; and in next page you can reach params like this:

```
function urlParam (name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
                      .exec(window.location.href);

    return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;
}
console.log(urlParam('email'));
```

Comment: Nowadays there's [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Examples) you can use to parse query strings, assuming you don't need IE support. (Your version probably needs a [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) but you might get away without that for email addresses I guess.)